# Why is CSS not working on my PHP generated elements?

Tags: php, html, css, css-selectors

On my index.php file I included a PHP file (test1.php) that echo's some strings and generates a `<h3>` element and a `<p>` element with some content. Upon loading my site I noticed that those element were not reacting to my CSS but all other elements worked just fine.

I don't understand why not. I got it to work by reloading the CSS, but I don't understand why I would have to do that. Isn't PHP generating a complete HTML DOM tree before it sends it to the browser?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>PHP & SQL Start AMPPS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="PHP, SQL, Start">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" 
      rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tomorrow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/main.css?v=<?php echo time();?>">
    <!-- The echo time forces the css to reload everytime -->
    
</head>

<body>
    <header id="pageheader">
        <h1>AMPPS Server</h1>
        <p>Let's do some PHP & SQL</p>
    </header>
    
    <article id="HelloWorld-PHP" class="PHP-test" >
        <h2>PHP test: Hello World</h2>
        <?php include 'PHP/helloWorld.php';?>
    </article>

    <article id="php-test1" class="PHP-test">
        <h2>PHP test: 1</h2>
        <?php include 'PHP/test1.php';?>
    </article>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the test1.php file I include:

```
<?php //test1.php
    $username = "Fred Smith";
    echo "Username = " . $username;
    echo "<br>";
    $current_user = $username;
    echo "Currentuser = " . $current_user;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h3>Sam's Corner</h3> <p>Now that there is the Tec-9, a crappy spray gun from South Miami. This gun is advertised as the most popular gun in American crime. Do you believe that shit? It actually says that in the little book that comes with it: the most popular gun in American crime. Like they're actually proud of that shit.  </p>"
?>
```

This is my CSS:

```
::root {
    --kleur-snow: rgb(255,250,250);
}
body {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: var(--kleur-snow);
    font-family: "Tomorrow", "sans-serif";
}

#pageheader {
    font-family: "Orbitron", "sans-serif";
    background-color: teal;
    color: white;
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
    padding: .4em;
    border: solid 2px black;
}
#pageheader h1 {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#pageheader p {
    margin: .5em 0 0 0;
}

.PHP-test {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin: 0 0 .4em 0;
    padding: .5em;
}
.PHP-test h2 {
    margin: 0 0 .3em 0;
}
.PHP-test h3 {
    margin: .5em 0 .3em 0;
}
.PHP-test p {
    margin: 0 0 .2em 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by reloading css?

Comment: _"Isn't PHP generating a complete HTML DOM tree before it sends it to the browser?"_ - Only if you've added code for it. PHP doesn't do anything unless you tell it to. But yes, the PHP code is generated on the server before it's returned to the client (the browser). So as far as the browser is concerned (where the CSS is applied), there's no difference between a page generated through PHP or is pure HTML. If you notice a difference, then the output can't be identical, or you've updated the CSS while the browser reuses a cached version instead.

Comment: @GokulnathP By reloading CSS I mean that by refreshing the page I also refresh the CSS. What that tells me is that the `<h3>` element and the `<p>` element that are not responding, get displayed after that the CSS in the cache had done it's work. I don't get that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That's just the thing. There is no difference between the cached CSS and the reloaded CSS. The `<h3>` and `<p>` elements are somehow invisible to the CSS if I don't add `?v=<?php echo time();?>` to the CSS link in the `<head>` of the document.

Comment: Delete `?v=<?php echo time();?>` from css link and try to open page in incognito mode. It should work as expected now. If yes, then problem is in cash.

Comment: @Volex Thanks for the tip. I tried what you said and it worked just fine. I am using a AMPPS local server and the browser reload button on the server doesn't seem to reload things as I expect it to. If I just type the URL into the search bar, the CSS works just fine. It looks like the AMPPS server can keep track of changes to the site even if you reload it. If I want a fresh version of my site I need input the URL again. Must be an automatic session or something.